# Is there a way to close source a Chrome extension or Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, obfuscation

The closest approach to close sourcing I've seen is to obfuscate the code. Is there a better way since obfuscation doesn't make reverse engineering impossible? In fact, is reverse engineering actually quite simple?

Comment: Continue to improve the code you do write, so at least it won't be too embarassing if it gets traced back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Javascript executes on the client computer (not the server) there's not much you can do beyond obfuscation unfortunately. Unless you use AJAX and run the important bits of the code on a server somewhere then it'll always be reverse engineerable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How about user1028775's suggestion about having the code as an NPAPI plugin?

Comment: Doesn't work with IE beyond version 5.5 so not a particularly viable solution (unless you can force your users to use a different browser). You may also find that many users don't want to run an NPAPI plugin for security reasons (correctly or not).

Comment: But since it's a Firefox/Chrome extension, it shouldn't need to accommodate for IE users, right?

Comment: Right you are - sorry, I was thinking in general terms. Give it a shot with something simple and see how it goes I guess - never used them personally (for the reasons highlighted above), but if it works smoothly this is the perfect time to use them I guess!

Comment: If you do go the obscuration route, check out the [closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/). Because this can do optimisations like inlining and renaming variables, the code is very different to the original, and much harder to understand.

Comment: @Kate: NPAPI plugins will trigger big red warnings when your Chrome extension installs. And addons.mozilla.org won't accept the extension unless you provide them the source code of that plugin. But other than that - it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in (compiled/binary) NPAPI plugins.